# Find minimal n such that n-th Bernstein approximation is good with error at most 10^(-8)

Tags: python, optimization, numerical-methods

Find minimal n such that n-th Bernstein approximation is good with error at most 10^(-8) with respect to uniform norm on [0,1] for function x^3. As in the title, I am struggling to find such n. If this error was 10^(-2) it would be easy, but my program gets stuck when computing such high powers. Here is a program I wrote, which would be good for fiding small n, such that error is huge. But what about error 10^(-8)? The problem is that Bernstein polynomial has factor x^k(1-x)^(n-k) so when n is huge, there is a huge number of multiplication.

```
import scipy.special
import scipy.optimize
import pylab
import numpy
def cub(x):
    return x*x*x

def bernstein(k,n,x):
    a=scipy.special.binom(n, k)
    return cub(k/n)*a*x**k*(1-x)**(n-k)
def suma(n,x):
    s=0
    for k in range (0,n+1):
        s=s+bernstein(k,n,x)
    return s
def error(x,n):
    b=abs(cub(x)-suma(n,x))
    return b
def errorn(x,n):
    b=-error(x,n)
    return b
a=0
for n in range (1,100):
    def funkcja(x):
        f=errorn(x,n)
        return f
    normax=scipy.optimize.fminbound(funkcja, 0, 1)
    norma=-errorn(normax,n)
    if norma<0.01:
        a=norma
        break
    else:
        continue
print(n)
```

Comment: Not sure what to think about this question for this site, it seems to be more about math (knowing a good approximation algorithm) than 'programming' (implementation). - - Also minor point: I assume your error should be at most x (instead of at least)

Comment: From which package are you importing "bernoulli"? For me it fails with name error.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this comment. I wasn't sure where to put this question as an excersice is to find the exact n. I thought a direct approach was to be used, because approximating is going to deviate the result. Hence I wanted to program this direct approach, but I am not very good at programming, so I thought maybe somehow it could be done. As to the other comment, it should have been bernstein instead of bernoulli, I have changed names before uploading and forgot about it.

Comment: Are you sure this is a programming task? Usually such impossible numbers are given when one wants to exclude a computational solution. You can, with a little calculus, find the exact expression of the Bernstein sum (it is a third degree polynomial) and from there find bounds on the error and thus on admissible values of n. n~10^8 seems unavoidable. ==> If you want to go this way, move the question to math.SE.

Comment: What you can do with your program is a log-log plot of the error vs. n. Then extrapolate the trend to the quantities of the task.

Comment: Thanks @Dr.LutzLehmann I calculated the exact expression of Bernstein polynomial (I forgot before that it would be a third degree polynomial that's why I was trying to program it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference of the Bernstein sum to the original function `x^3` is

```
x*(1-x)*(1-2*x)/n^2 + 3*x^2*(1-x)/n
```

Now use upper bounds for these coefficients to find bounds on `n`. This gives, determining the maxima of the coefficient functions graphically,

```
error <= 0.0963/n^2+0.44445/n <= 1e-8

n >= 4.4445e7 + 0.963e7/n
```

so that the minimal `n` is `4.4445e7+1`. With a more careful analysis this can be reduced to `n=44444445`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, however I got different Bernstein polynomial, could you take a look? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3461199/calculating-third-bernstein-polynomial-for-function-x3